# Can not get value with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php

I do not know why php can return value from data.
Below are form:

```
<form id="emailform" method="post" >
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
            <div class="result"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="generate" id="generate" value="Save" >
</form>
```

and Ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#generate').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href, 
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data:{'email':  email}, 
                success: function(html) {
                    alert(email);
                     $('.result').html('<p>Thank you for providing email. </p>');
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#emailform').text('An error occurred');
                }
            });
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
     $email = $_GET['email'];
      echo $email;
?>
```

After click Save button, I run echo $email but it returns nothing. How can you help me for this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Any another suggestion for me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a POST request in you ajax but in the php script you are catching an $_get request try changing your php script to this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']){
 $email = $_POST['email'];
  echo $email;
 }else{
 echo 'email is not set';
}
?>
```

or doing the reverse changing the ajax call to get like @Dj said :

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var url = window.location.href;          
        $('#generate').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            email = $('#email').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: url+'?email='+email, 
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                         $('.result').html('<p>Thank you for providing email. </p>'+response);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#emailform').text('An error occurred');
                    }
                });
        }); 
    }); 
    </script>
```

and the php script to :

```
   <?php
if (isset($_GET['email']){
$email = $_GET['email'];
 echo $email;
 }else{
echo 'email is not set';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hi. thank you for your answer but it returns email is not set. why that?

Comment: It's easier to just edit the `post` in your ajax call to `get`

Comment: @SuperDJ It seems that not working. I do not know why.

Comment: @BuiPhuc What you could do is append the data onto the url. Making it: `url: this.href+'?email='+email,` making the data key useless

Comment: @SuperDJ Can you make an answer below?

Comment: @BuiPhuc see a made the SuperDJ proposition

Comment: @BuiPhuc try the script now.

Comment: @M0ns1f: HI. I tried but it seems not to work. An error occurred

Comment: @M0ns1f. Do you know why?

Comment: Hi @M0ns1f: Browser returns an error with href: domain.com/path/undefined?email=myemail@gmail.com. Why it is undefined?

Comment: @BuiPhuc corrected see try it now, add the url from `window.location.href`

Answer (score 2):

You can make the AJAX call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.href+'?email='+email, 
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text', 
    success: function(html) {
        alert(email);
        $('.result').html('<p>Thank you for providing email. </p>');
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#emailform').text('An error occurred');
    }
  });
```

Or for short https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/:

```
$.get( this.href+'?email='+email, function( data ) {
 console.log(data);
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

For the receiving PHP part I think you are better off with using: `if( !empty ( $_GET ['email'] ) )`. `empty` does the same as `isset` but at the same time checks if there is a value. With just `isset` you can still send an empty email.

Since you're sending the data to the page itself you can make it even easier. You can even delete the whole AJAX request if you just change the method in your form to `get` instead of `post`

Comment: Thank you but It returns "An error occurred" after click

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Updated answer again

Answer (score -1):

Just change your $_GET['email'] to $_POST['email'] or change type in ajax call to get and it should work flawlessly.